# Django runserver throws error during boot

Tags: django

Am trying to run a django server, the server was running fine, but after reverting to old git commit, it started to throw the below error when I do  `python manage.py runserver`

**Error**

```
(venv_prd) D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 95, in <module>
    class Group(models.Model):
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 156, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1588, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1057, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 192, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 156, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 79, in gettext
    return _trans.gettext(message)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 285, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 198, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 90, in __init__
    self._init_translation_catalog()
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 130, in _init_translation_catalog
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
  File "D:\projects\rd-portal\rdportal\venv_prd\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 123, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\gettext.py", line 523, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\gettext.py", line 254, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\gettext.py", line 345, in _parse
    magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I can't tell what is the root cause of the error, eventhough when I copied and ran the project on another PC, it worked find.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your translation files. Most likely you have an empty `.mo` file somewhere.

Delete the file and run `python manage.py compilemessages` to create a valid `.mo` file.

Comment: now am getting `OSError: No translation files found for default language en-us.`

Comment: For `runserver` or for `compilemessages`?

Comment: Which file(s) did you delete?

Comment: `django.mo`, yet I can see they have been recreated but all have 0 bytes

Comment: I guess you delete all `.mo` files, including the ones of Django itself, not only the empty ones. You have to re-install Django then.